# Internet Explorer 7 & 8 issue with Prototype 1.6.1 - Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e

Tags: internet-explorer, prototypejs

I'm at a loss. I found a few things that mentioned IE needed to have the response type specified and I changed that to text/html and that did nothing for me.

There Error:

Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e.  prototype.js, line 1564

Points to in prototype.js:

```
if((readyState > 2 && !Prototype.Browser.IE) || readyState == 4) {
  this.status       = this.getStatus();
  this.statusText   = this.getStatusText();
  this.responseText = String.interpret(transport.responseText); <!--- ERROR is here --->
  this.headerJSON   = this._getHeaderJSON();
}
```

The function called from an onClick() in an href:

```
function f(op, cl) {
    if(op && cl) {
            new Ajax.Updater('favorites-' + cl, '/fav.php',
            {
                    onComplete: function(transport) {
                            if(transport.responseText == 1 && cl) $('favorites-' + cl).remove();
                            else return transport.responseText;
                            },
                    onException: function(r, e) {
                                    alert('Updater ' + e);
                            },
                    method: 'get',
                    parameters: { cl: cl, op: op },
                    encoding: 'UTF-8',
                    contentType: 'text/html'
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Error C00CE56E typically happens when your script returns an encoding (by Content-Type charset parameter or `<?xml encoding`) that IE doesn't recognise, for example if you say ‘utf8’ instead of the correct ‘UTF-8’. This has to be fixed at the server-side.

What is the Content-Type header your server is sending?

Comment: Hmm, that's kinda of what I thought, however, after looking at the headers, the server side set charset is utf-8, see below:

Date Fri, 09 Oct 2009 01:22:40 GMT
Server Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_gzip/1.3.26.1a PHP/5.3.0
Vary *
X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.0
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma no-cache
Keep-Alive timeout=15, max=98
Connection Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Content-Type text/html; charset=text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: I edited this answer; we just ran into this issue, and the correct charset is "UTF-8", not "utf-8". Honestly I don't know if the case matters, but we did it in all caps and it solved our problem. Also be sure that you're looking at the headers of the actual request that has the problem, not a generic request, as the headers may be getting overwritten.

Comment: A header of `Content-Type: text/html;charset:utf-8` causes this error in IE 9.  It should be `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`. Notice the space, the equals sign and the uppercase encoding. It's interesting that other browsers don't say a thing. Have a look at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17