# $.getJSON display the Error: Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e in IE

Tags: php, codeigniter, internet-explorer, jquery

```
$.getJSON(base_url+"search/ajax_get_results", params, function( data ) {
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        alert(key+' : '+val);return false;
    });
}).error( function( xhr, status, error ) {
    console.log( error );
});
```

I used,

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

But, not working for me.

Comment: What happens if you just do `header("Content-Type: application/json");`?  I don't use `charset` in my headers, and I've never seen this problem.

Comment: I found [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540750/internet-explorer-7-8-issue-with-prototype-1-6-1-could-not-complete-the-oper?rq=1#comment11229448_1540876) on another question, and it may help here.  Try `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");`.